# Getting post title in widget that is in footer

Tags: php, wordpress

How do I get the current post title inside of a widget that is in the footer?  I'm assuming the loop won't be available.

I tried get_the_title() in shortcode.  When I type the shortcode into the widget, I see the shortcode literal rather than the output.

Comment: Does [this (first result after a search on google)](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-get-post-title-outside-the-loop) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are talking about WordPress themes footer... so if you're in a post (single.php) it will work as expected:

$x = get_the_title(); // To assign $x the post title value

the_title(); // To echo the title directly

Comment: That does get the title inside of a post.  But I just discovered I need to do it in a widget in the footer.  I've updated the question.  I changed your code into shortcode but the widget doesn't like shortcode.  I see the shortcode literal in the output.